# Is passing arguments related by conversion to a template function call that uses template argument deduction bad thing?

Tags: c++, overloading, template-argument-deduction

AFAIK overloading a function for types that are relative by conversion or a function call that needs some cast applied to the argument to match a best a match are of bad design.

```
void foo(int)
{
    std::cout << "foo(int)\n";
}

void foo(float)
{
    std::cout << "foo(float)\n";
}


int main()
{
    foo(5.3);// ambiguous call
    foo(0u); // ambiguous call
}
```

Because `5.3` is of type double so it can be equally converted to either `float` or `int` thus there are more than best match for the call consequently the call is ambiguous. In the second call the same thing: `0u` is of type `unsigned int` which can be converted to `int` or `float` equally thus the call is ambiguous.

- To disambiguate the calls I can use a an explicit `cast`:

  ```
  foo(static_cast<float>(5.3)); // calls foo(float)
  foo(static_cast<int>(0u)); // calls foo(int)
  ```
- The code now works but it is a bad design because that breaks the principle of Function overloading where the compiler is the responsible for choosing the best match function for a call depending on the arguments passed it.
- Until here I'm OK. But what about templates argument deduction? :

*The compiler applies only a few conversions on the arguments passed in to function template call to deduce the type of template arguments.

- So the compiler doesn't apply arithmetic conversion nor integral promotion but instead it often generates a new version that best math the call:

  ```
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T)
    {
        std::cout << "foo(" << typeid(T).name() << ")\n";
    }

    int main()
    {

        foo(5.3); // calls foo(double)
        foo(0u); // calls foo(unsigned)
    }
  ```
- Now it works fine: the compiler generates two versions of `foo` one with `double` and the second with `unsigned`.
- The thing that matters me: Is it a bad idea to pass arguments of related types into a function template that uses template argument deduction for its arguments?
- Or the problem is in the language itself? Because the compiler generates versions that can be relative by conversion?

Comment: This seems to be a little opinion-based to me. Also, in the last bullet, I think you mean *language*, not *compiler*.

Comment: @cigien: Yea That's what I meant.

Comment: Ok, then edit the question please.

Comment: @cigien: edited.

Comment: `Or the problem is in the language itself?` What problem? `Is it a bad idea to pass arguments of related types into a function template that uses template argument deduction for its arguments?` What is "bad"? It just depends on what behavior _you want_ your code to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or the problem is in the language itself? Because the compiler generates versions that can be relative by conversion?

Okay, they are related by conversion. Now which one should the compiler generate? What deterministic algorithm do you propose it employ to choose the best function to instantiate? Should it parse the entire translation unit first to figure out the best match, or should it still parse top to bottom and keep a "running best" function?

Now, assuming those questions are answered. What happens when you modify your code a bit? What happens if you include a header that instantiates an even better function? You didn't really change *your* code, but its behavior is still altered, possibly very drastically.

Considering the design headache it is for the language, and the potential chaos this behavior can bring unto unsuspecting code, it'd be a very bad idea to try and make compilers do this.

So no, it's not a language problem. The current behavior is really the sanest choice, even if it's not always what we *want*, it's something we can learn to *expect*.

> The thing that matters me<sup>[sic]</sup>: Is it a bad idea to pass arguments of related types into a function template that uses template argument deduction for its arguments?

There's no way to answer it generally for all cases. There are no silver bullets. It could be exactly what your overload set needs to do. Or it could be that you need to build a more refined set of function(s) (templates) that interact with overload resolution via SFINAE or more modern techniques. For instance, you could do this in C++20

```
template <std::integral I>
void foo(I)
{
   //
}

template <std::floating_point F>
void foo(F)
{
   //
}
```

The concepts constrain each template to work only with a specific *family* of types. That's one way to build the overload set you wanted in your first example, avoid the ambiguity, and work with exact types as templates are designed.

Comment: Ah, *family*, that's the word I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

In your first program containing the overload set of `foo` with `int` and `float`, the language rules say that calls like:

```
foo(5.3); 
foo(0u);
```

are ambiguous. Overload resolution rules say that in both those calls, the conversions needed for the function arguments to match the parameters are tied, resulting in both candidates being equally good matches.

---

Your solution using a single function template could work, depending on your use case. One potential issue is that every single call to `foo` with a different argument type will result in a completely different instantiation of `foo`. Another is that this function template will accept any argument type for which the definition of `foo` is valid. Neither of these behaviors may be what you desire.

---

Based on your overload set in the first program, and the `static_cast`s in your code to explicitly call specific versions, it seems that you actually want to group `int` and `unsigned`, i.e integral types into one category, and `float` and `double`, i.e. floating point types into another. You could implement this in a number of different ways, e.g. by providing an exhaustive overload set that covers all the types that you care about.

The approach I would recommend is to implement the overload set with two function templates, each allowing one family of types. From C++20, you could implement it like this:

```
void foo(std::integral auto)
{
    std::cout << "foo(integral)\n";
}

void foo(std::floating_point auto)
{
    std::cout << "foo(floating_point)\n";
}
```

You can also achieve the same effect before C++20, with a little more syntax, and using SFINAE and other template meta-programming techniques.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o3G44s).